# Scattered data interpolation (lat,long and temperature )

Tags: python, interpolation, projection, rasterio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG8UQ.png)I managed to to the interpolation with this below code ,my problem is with the projection, when I open the final output on `GIS software`(Erdas imagine) it is located not correctly in California my output is not appropriate, is there a way of not calculating `affline` from my coordinates, I don't want to put them manually

```
lon = data2['Longitude'].values

lon2=data2['Longitude2'].values

lat = data2['Lattitude2'].values

t = data2['Temparature ℃'].values

xp, yp,_= to_proj.transform_points(ccrs.Geodetic(), lon, lat).T

x_m,y_m,t_m=remove_nan_observations(xp, yp, t)


x,y,z=interpolate_to_grid(x_m, y_m, t_m, interp_type='linear', hres=1000, 
                minimum_neighbors=4, gamma=0.25, kappa_star=5.052, search_radius=1000, rbf_func='linear', rbf_smooth=1)


new_transform1 = Affine(1883.50, 0.0, 406063.73814945, 0.0, 2300.95, 4674584.0)

image = rasterio.open(' minus_Central_meridian_ - lat.tiff', 'w', driver='GTiff',
                        height = z.shape[0], width = z.shape[1],
                        count=1, dtype=str(z.dtype),
                  crs='+proj=utm +zone=10 +south+ellps=WGS84+EPSG:857+ +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs',transform=new_transform1
                  )


image.write(z, 1)
image.close()
```

Thank you in advance!!!!!

see my output It was supposed to be aligned well in California but its inappropriate